# Need sub for Windows 10 Home msg.exe

Tags: msg

Windows 10 Home edition pulled msg.exe.

I need a sub that I can use to pop up message to the local user, NOT THE NETWORK, from a batch script.

Many thanks,
-T

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a VBS script, something like:

```
set wshell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")

msg = "<No message provided>"
title = "Information"
timeout = 0

if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then
    msg = wscript.arguments.item(0)
    if wscript.arguments.count > 1 then
        title = wscript.arguments.item(1)
        if wscript.arguments.count > 2 then
            timeout = wscript.arguments.item(2)
        end if
    end if
end if

wscript.quit(wshell.popup(msg, timeout, title, 0))
```

Just put that into `paxmsg.vbs` and call it with:

```
cscript /nologo paxmsg.vbs "My text"
```

or:

```
cscript /nologo paxmsg.vbs "Text with 5s timeout" "My Title" 5
```

The basic usage is <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
cscript /nologo paxmsg.vbs <optionalText> <optionalTitle> <optionalTimeout>
```

and you can discern the default values for each parameter from the first few lines of the script itself.

`ERRORLEVEL` can be used in your batch script to detect whether `OK` was pressed or it timed out (assuming non-zero timeout value, of course).

---

By way, of example, the following invocation:

```
cscript /nologo paxmsg.vbs "Dialog box with sample text" "Pax's dialog box"
```

results in:

> [image]

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Note that using `cscript` is most likely the behaviour you want, in that it will wait until the dialog box *closes* before continuing on with your batch script. If you want it to continue immediately, you can use `wscript` instead.

Comment: Anything that is not a vbs script?

Comment: @Todd: yes, I could write a C++ program which does the same thing. But, since VBScript has been a core part of Windows for quite a while now, it's probably easier just to use that.

Comment: Todd, yes, an executable would be the best format but I *wasn't* offering to write it since it would give you nothing that the already-existing `cscript` executable (which comes with Windows) gives you with the script I provided. You asked a question on how to do something, I provided an easy way. If you want to go off and do it in a *harder* way, that's fine, but I'm not keen on assisting in that :-)

Comment: I just wanted to stay away from VBS Scripts

Comment: I was hoping to find someone that had already written collection of exe's for such.  I also do not like the security issues with VBS

Comment: @Todd, that would probably have been instantly closed: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: Is there a way to get this forum to eMail you when someone responds?

Comment: Not easily, since it's *not* meant to be a forum/conversation-board. You'll be notified by virtue of the fact I'm referencing your name (@Todd) in messages but, since the intent is a Q&A for *everyone* in the future rather than just the asker, I don't believe that's high priority. You can ask over at meta if you wish.